# Azure Data Factory SQL Sink parameter str1?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

What is "Str1" ? Is this a general string type instead of varchar or nvarhcar?

Example:

```
"sink":
{
    "type": "SqlSink",
    "SqlWriterTableType": "MarketingType",
    "SqlWriterStoredProcedureName": "spOverwriteMarketing", 
    "storedProcedureParameters":
            {
                "stringData": 
                {
                    "value": "str1"     
                }
            }
}
```

[Reference](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-sqlserver-connector/#invoking-stored-procedure-for-sql-sink)

*** Updated ***

**My problem is now resolved.** These parameters are the parameter values. For  dynamic parameters you need not specify them here in the JSON.

Comment: Hi Alvin, could you please take a look at my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45032243/keep-only-the-most-recent-row-of-data-in-data-factory/45032800#45032800

Comment: Do you think I can use the method provided in here for my issue? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-invoke-stored-procedure-from-copy-activity

Answer (score 3):

"Str1" is just a general string type. You can see the schema for a data pipeline defined here: https://datafactories.schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-09-01/Microsoft.DataFactory.Pipeline.json (You would want to look at sqlSink specifically)

Comment: please answer the question and don't just post links here. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that "Str1" is a string type? I deduced that this is just a sample string value.