# Keep only the most recent row of data in data factory

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, etl, azure-data-factory

I am using Data factory to create our staging area, the problem is whenever source data changes, we add a new row to staging tables.

For instance, assume we have the following data:

```
ID          Fields             created              edited
100        ----------        '2017-07-01'         '2017-07-05'
```

this will be stored in our staging tables like this:

```
  ID          Fields             created              edited
  100        ----------        '2017-07-01'            null 
  100        ----------        '2017-07-01'         '2017-07-05'
```

Selecting the most recent row is expensive and We don't want that. How do you think we can avoid storing duplicate IDs in staging?

I assume on creating the pipelines, there should be a way to update the data if the ID already exists in staging.
the query format in data factory is like this:

```
$$Text.Format('select * from <<table>> where <<column>> >= \'{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}\' AND <<column>> < \'{1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}\'', WindowStart, WindowEnd)
```

Comment: You could do a `MERGE` something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-invoke-stored-procedure-from-copy-activity)?

Comment: If exists (select 1 from table where id=@id) update statement where id =@id else insert statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. It goes like this:

I added a temp table into our data warehouse, before inserting data into Staging, first data comes into these temp tables, I remove those which already exist in staging tables then do a fresh insert. In this way, I will always keep the most recent data in the staging area and I won't have to use row_number() functions when joining staging tables to create DW.

I am not sure if it's the best approach, but it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here i think most recent record is considered by edited column  ,Try this below code

```
;WITH CTE (ID,Fields,created,edited)
AS
(
SELECT 100,'------------' ,'2017-07-01',   null     UNION ALL
SELECT 100,'------------ ','2017-07-01','2017-07-05' 
)
SELECT ID,Fields,created,edited FROM
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition by ID ORDER BY edited DESC ) RecentRecord FROM CTE
)DT
WHERE DT.RecentRecord=1
```

Result

```
ID   Fields         created     edited
------------------------------------------
100 ------------    2017-07-01  2017-07-05
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not my question. have you used data factory?